# How can I calculate sum and average in while loop (python?)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Serendipity Booksellers has a book club that awards points to its customers
based on the number of books purchased each month. The points are awarded as
follows:
• If a customer purchases 0 books, he or she earns 0 points.
• If a customer purchases 2 books, he or she earns 5 points.
• If a customer purchases 4 books, he or she earns 15 points.
• If a customer purchases 6 books, he or she earns 30 points.
• If a customer purchases 8 or more books, he or she earns 60 points.
Write a python program that asks the user to enter the number of books that he or she
has purchased this month, then displays the number of points awarded.
However, my professor asks me to add:

1. Use a while loop for allowing the program to run repeatedly.
2. Prompt user to enter the number of books.  Also, prompt that to stop the program, the user must enter a negative number.
3. Each time user enters the number of books.  Numbers can be any positive number,  0 or more. The program should calculate points correctly.
4. After the program stops, it prints the number of users, the total points offered to users, and the average points given to each user.
5. Make sure the output print is descriptive and meaningful
6. Include minimum but meaningful comments to understand what your program does.

Here is what I did

```
# Prompt: To stop the programming, you just enter the negative number 
print("To stop the programming, you just need to enter the negative number.")

# Prompt user to enter the number of books
while True:
    books = float(input("\nEnter your number of book purchased this month: "))
    if books < 0:
        break
    elif books<2:
            print("Your number of book purchased this month is ",books)
            point=0
            print("Your total point is",point)
    elif books<4:
            print("Your number of book purchased this month is ",books)
            point=5
            print("Your total point is",point)
    elif books<6:
            print("Your number of book purchased this month is ",books)
            point=15
            print("Your total point is",point)
    elif books<8:
            print("Your number of book purchased this month is ",books)
            point=30
            print("Your total point is",point)
    else:
            print("Your number of book purchased this month is ",books)
            point=60
            print("Your total point is",point)
```

I do not know how to prints the number of users, the total points offered to users, and the average points are given to each user after the user stop the program

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I do not know how to it prints the number of users, the total points offered to users and the average points given to each user after the user stop the program

Comment: It's easy to get caught up in all the context, but the issue you're facing is probably fundamental across all problems - try to focus on that. I'm not going to read your assignment

Comment: Yes, start by forgetting about all the details except how to work out how many users have entered a number of books.

Comment: @HarveyHardy, the users can be saved into an array where each index will represent the customer/user and the value will represent the points collected. At the end, you can get the average easily

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. We're volunteers here and most of what you've posted is completely irrelevant. Do the work of reducing your problem to as minimal a case as possible.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not know how to it prints the number of users, the total points offered to users and the average points given to each user after the user stop the program

For total users, make a variable `user_count` which is the count of users recorded.

For the total points, make a variable `point_total` which is the cumulative points of users recorded.

For the average points, divide `point_total` by `user_count`.

I also note you have a lot of repeated code. You can reduce this easily:

```
user_count = 0
point_total = 0

print("To stop the program, just enter a negative number.")

while True:
    books = int(input("\nEnter your number of books purchased this month: "))
    if books < 0:
        break
    elif books < 2:
        point = 0
    elif books < 4:
        point = 5
    elif books < 6:
        point = 15
    elif books < 8:
        point = 30
    else:
        point = 60

    print("Your number of books purchased this month is", books)
    print("Your total points are", point)

    user_count += 1
    point_total += point

if user_count > 0:
    point_average = point_total / user_count
else:
    point_average = 0

print("Total number of users recorded", user_count)
print("Total number of points recorded", point_total)
print("Average number of points recorded", point_average)
```

---

### Bonus

If you want to get really fancy, you could use a dictionary to store the points versus their thresholds, and use the `next` method plus a generator expression to map books to a points value.

```
# Map points to the maximum books required.
thresholds = {
    0: 2,
    5: 4,
    15: 6,
    30: 8,
    60: float('inf'),
}
...
while True:
    books = int(input("\nEnter your number of books purchased this month: "))
    if books < 0:
        break
    # Find the first value for points which is less than 
    # its maximum number of required books.
    points = next(
        points 
        for points, threshold in thresholds.items() 
        if books < threshold
    )
```